# Student search application using a JFrame that keeps freezing when the search button is pushed

Tags: java

I got a question during my final exam and it basically consisted off these questions:

1. Create a JFrame.
2. Have a JList with 3 specific student numbers.
3. Have a search button underneath.
4. When search is selected the students highest, lowest and average mark is displayed on right side of the JFrame. (I used separate TextFields to display this)
5. The 3 students student ID, test mark, assignment mark and exam mark are saved in a text file.

The basic concept of this JFrame is to allow for easy searching of results between each student.

This is the code I used when the search button is pushed:

```
private void SearchBActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    // Searching for student
    String searching;
    if (StudentNum.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
        searching = "10111";
    } else if (StudentNum.getSelectedIndex() == 1) {
        searching = "10112";
    } else if (StudentNum.getSelectedIndex() == 2) {
        searching = "10113";
    }

    Scanner SearchFile = null;

    Scanner w = new Scanner(System.in);
    File currentFile = new File("student.txt");
    boolean match = false;
    try {
        SearchFile = new Scanner(currentFile);

        searching = w.nextLine();
        // while loop that searches the text file
        while (SearchFile.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = SearchFile.nextLine();
            String[] read = line.split(",");
            String studentsearch = read[0];

            if (line.contains(searching) && searching.equals(searching)) {
                match = true;

                String[] details = line.split(",");
                String studNum = details[0];
                String test = details[1];
                String assignment = details[2];
                String exam = details[3];

                test1 = Double.parseDouble(details[1]);
                assignment1 = Double.parseDouble(details[2]);
                exam1 = Double.parseDouble(details[3]);


            }

        }
        if (!match) {
            System.out.println("Student cannot be found");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (SearchFile != null) {
                SearchFile.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    // Calculating avegerage
    averageresult = test1 * assignment1 * exam1;
    AveResult.setText(averageresult + "%");

    if (test1 >= assignment1 && test1 >= exam1) {

        HResult.setText(test1 + "%");

    } else if (assignment1 >= test1 && assignment1 >= exam1) {

        HResult.setText(assignment1 + "%");

    } else if (exam1 >= test1 && exam1 >= assignment1) {

        HResult.setText(exam1 + "%");
    }

    if (test1 < assignment1 && test1 < exam1) {

        LResult.setText(test1 + "%");

    } else if (assignment1 < test1 && assignment1 < exam1) {

        LResult.setText(assignment1 + "%");

    } else if (exam1 < test1 && exam1 < assignment1) {

        LResult.setText(exam1 + "%");
    }


}
```

Whenever I push the search button the JFrame freezes and doesn't want to respond to anything. It wont let me select anything else in the JFrame or close the JFrame.

The information in the text file was displayed like this:

```
10111,35,55,75
10112,30,30,30
10113,75,55,88
```

Comment: Are you entering the search value in console `searching = w.nextLine();` ?

Comment: Comment out that line I think you don't need it here as you are already setting the value for searching based on the conditions.

Comment: Thank you, I realized I was running a scanner in the background which was preventing me from doing anything else in the JFrame. The problem is now solved and I did some basic math changes so that my calculations are a bit more accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sara says, problem in line `Scanner w = new Scanner(System.in);`
System.in wait until user enters a line in the console, and this block your thread, so the interface doesn't respond.

Why do you don't use break; when you find something? There is any reason? 
And there for you too:

Your form will be freeze because of this reason - your search executed in the same thread as the interface, so when you execute something that needs time, be your thread work only with search not render interface. 
How fix it?
U need to do this search it another thread, that will executed parallel (it's complicated but what you need to know that it's parallel, or asynchronous) with main thread.

Answer (score 0):

This is what my updated code looks like with a few changes to make it run a bit smoother.

```
private void SearchBActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    // Searching for student
    String searching = null;
    if (StudentNum.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
        searching = "10111";
    } else if (StudentNum.getSelectedIndex() == 1) {
        searching = "10112";
    } else if (StudentNum.getSelectedIndex() == 2) {
        searching = "10113";
    }

    Scanner SearchFile = null;

    File currentFile = new File("student.txt");
    boolean match = false;
    try {
        SearchFile = new Scanner(currentFile);

        // while loop that searches the text file
        while (SearchFile.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = SearchFile.nextLine();
            String[] read = line.split(",");
            String studentsearch = read[0];

            if (line.contains(searching) && searching.equals(searching)) {
                match = true;

                String[] details = line.split(",");
                String studNum = details[0];
                String test = details[1];
                String assignment = details[2];
                String exam = details[3];

                test1 = Double.parseDouble(details[1]);
                assignment1 = Double.parseDouble(details[2]);
                exam1 = Double.parseDouble(details[3]);

            }

        }
        if (!match) {
            System.out.println("Student cannot be found");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (SearchFile != null) {
                SearchFile.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    // Calculating avegerage
    averageresult = Math.round((test1 + assignment1 + exam1) / 3);
    AveResult.setText(averageresult + "%");

    if (test1 >= assignment1 && test1 >= exam1) {

        HResult.setText(test1 + "%");

    } else if (assignment1 >= test1 && assignment1 >= exam1) {

        HResult.setText(assignment1 + "%");

    } else if (exam1 >= test1 && exam1 >= assignment1) {

        HResult.setText(exam1 + "%");
    }

    if (test1 < assignment1 && test1 < exam1) {

        LResult.setText(test1 + "%");

    } else if (assignment1 < test1 && assignment1 < exam1) {

        LResult.setText(assignment1 + "%");

    } else if (exam1 < test1 && exam1 < assignment1) {

        LResult.setText(exam1 + "%");
    }


}
```